# How to open solution explorer in visual studio 2019?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am a complete novice when it comes to Python and Visual Studio. I am watching a youtube tutorial about how to do a specific task and notice that the programmer has a window open up on his video. I have attached a screenshot of the section that is open on his screen.

After doing some research I believe it is called the solution explorer and you should be able to open it by `ctl` + `alt` + `L`. That does not work for me. Another way that it is suppose to open is be under the View tab, but nothing I could find allows me to open it.

Is this feature no longer used on visual studio 2019?

EDIT: I just realized their is a difference between Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code. I am currently using VS Code which was my problem.

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtsaM.png)